# Change file extension when IE is detected

Tags: javascript, html, svg, png

Is there a way to display *svg* instead of *png* image when IE is detected?

I found the following code on a different question, which outputs text for either `IE` or `noIE`.

```
function isIE() {
  var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
  return (ua.indexOf("MSIE ") > 0 || !! ua.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./));
}

document.body.innerHTML = isIE() ? '.png' : '.svg';
```

Could this be used to change *.svg* to *.png* inside an *img src* when IE is detected?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure, you just need to loop throught all your img elements and change the src attribute!? What have you tried?

Comment: simply render the markup with PHP, then there is no need to mess around within the DOM. IE8 also bugs with UTF-8 content-type headers, therefore checking server-side is rather solid.

Comment: OP: I assume you mean changed to a `png` if IE detected.. :)    @MartinZeitler so how do you suggest PHP knows its IE, please don't say agent sniffing.  Also question does not have PHP as tag so it's irrelevant.

Comment: @Keith will add an answer, `.indexOf` just becomes `pregmatch`, in order to port it. need a computer, first.

Comment: Checking what browser somebody uses by looking at the user agent is very 90's, and very unreliable.. If you just want to send PNG if SVG is not supported by the browser, use feature detection.  `typeof SVGRect !== "undefined"` will return true if you can use SVG.

Answer (score 0):

one can already detect IE with PHP, while rendering the page ...
and then either set a JavaScript variable or just set PHP object property, to have some `.getFilename()` method return the correct filename.

```
<?php
$user_agent = trim(strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]));
$pattern = "/msie\s(\d+)\.(\d+)/";
$suffix = 'png';

/* attempting to match the above regular expressions pattern */
if(preg_match($pattern, $user_agent, $matches)){
   // $major_version = $matches[1];
   // $minor_version = $matches[2];
   $suffix = 'svg';
}

/* and then output like */
echo '<img src="/images/example.'.$suffix.'"/>';

?>
```

in JavaScript (using jQuery), if you really want to perform DOM manipulation ...

```
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > 0) {
    $('img').each(function() {
        var $img = $(this);
        var imgsrc = $img.attr('src');
        $img.attr('src', imgsrc.replace(".png", ".svg"));
    });
}
```

would prefer the server-side method, simply because it is about **serving** resources - and one would need to replace quite early on, in order not to have the client request both resources, doubling up the amount of dropped requests. the server-side code runs before any of the DOM events happen, which is the advance here.

Comment: `please don't say agent sniffing`.. and what makes you think the OP is using PHP?.

Comment: If you can use PHP, why not make use of the [get_browser function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)?

Comment: @xander there are various methods, also `browscap.ini` ...both `preg_match` & `get_browser` should be quicker than having the full `browscap.ini` loaded.

Comment: @Keith regular expressions exist in pretty much any server-side scripting language and it is just an example - while I've also explained why a pure JavaScript solution is a complete misconception. it is not about which language is used, it is all about the time-line of the page and resource loading. the idea of serving a wrongful URL to the client, while being able to prevent that ...with PHP, one can even fallback, in case the SVG does not exist.

Comment: User Agent Sniffing, even if PHP / NodeJS / IIS, is still not a good idea, feature detection is the more modern way,. `is a complete misconception.`, this is were I think your wrong.  This is a classic example, some versions of IE handle SVG nicely, so now a user using say IE11 has the not so good PNG's, for no other reason than you have used the wrong way to render your page.  And what about browser X/Y/Z that doesn't also support SVG, site broken.. The list goes on, and is the reason user agent sniffing is not recommended.  Feature detection means your also future proofing.

Comment: @Keith in this case, checking for outdated versions numbers should suffice, because once features are being supported, they are barely being dropped again. if you want client-side feature detection, one can check that with `typeof SVGRect !== "undefined";` - the basic difference lies in between synchronous and asynchronous loading of resources, which dictates if server- or client-side checks make more sense.

Comment: @MartinZeitler It makes no difference if ServerSide / ClientSide, if done right.  `synchronous and asynchronous`  => what has this to do with deciding what libs to load?.  The only thing I can assume your refering to is loading the whole page in the initial `index.html`, but doing that is not very good for caching.  And what about browser XYZ, that you have never seen before, SVG or No-SVG?.  Anyway, like I say it's not a good idea, Mozzila will back me up on this one -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent